# Concurrent select and record creation in RDBMS

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency, rdbms

While creating url shortner, i have 2 different client instances that query for a tiny url and if not found then create a record in the rdbms and assign it to a URL sent by the client. i am using elastic search to query for the tiny url. My problem is concurrency management across the two different instances, when both simultaneusly query for same tiny url and since its not found , it will create a record with same tiny url assigned to 2 different urls which is wrong. How can this situation be avoided ?

Regards

Comment: The first thing would be to add a constraint in your db to prevent this problem. At least, this will generate an exception for the second insert.

Answer (score 1):

you should consider a exclusive lock on the part of your code in which you check for tiny url existence. for example:

```
private final static Object LOCK = new Object();//it should be defined as a shared variable between threads. 
synchronize(LOCK) {
    //check if tiny url exists or not. 
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an in-memory database like Redis instead of Elasticsearch to check for tiny urls' existence.

Comment: Note that this could cost a lot of time. Especially if the problem is not frequent, you could end up with a single thread usage to solve a 1/1.000.000 request.

Comment: it depends on the operation you are going to do in synchronized block of your code. In the problem described, checking the existence of a url would not cost that much. Moreover, it depends how you design your architecture by which you are going to do such a operation to cost less. But generally, in a normal situation cost of such a operation would not make any serious problem in performance.

Comment: Well the "atomic operation" need to be a `SELECT` and optional `INSERT`. Two I/O operations, this can easily takes 100ms based on the server, number of index,... Reducing the amount of URL managed to 10 per second. That's why I proposed another approach using an exception. But based on the usage, this could works too

Comment: I myself would not do such an implementation to put all such IO ones in my synchronized block. One possible optimized implementation: set a boolean variable in the block and then do the suitable operation out of the block based on the variable.